# How do I access my original HttpServletRequest object in my Spring authentication success handler method?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, request

I'm using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.  How do I access the original request object in the authentication success handler method?  When I submit my spring security form, I submit three parameters, the username, the password, and a third token (with param name = "token").  I have tried this …

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate")
public String authenticate() 
{
    final HttpServletRequest origRequest = 
                ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.
                        currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    String token = origRequest.getParameter("token");
```

However, the value "token" is always null, even though I know its not when I submit the request.  Here's how I configure my Spring security …

```
<beans:bean id="springboardUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter" 
    class="org.collegeboard.springboard.dido.security.SpringboardUsernamePasswordUrlAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/failure"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/pdregistration/authenticate" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Thanks for your help, - Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to late. After successfull authentication your user was **redirected** by SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler to /authenticate. If you need access to previous HTTP request then just provide your own implementation for **authenticationSuccessHandler**. At this moment you will be able to get your token:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // grab your token here from request
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}

<beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:bean
        class="com.domain.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/pdregistration/authenticate" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

Comment: I see where you are grabbing the token, but how do you then pass it on to the method I call "authenticate"?

Comment: the token grabbed in onAuthenticationSuccess handler should be then stored somewhere your app can access it from. An obvious suggestion would be session-scoped bean, or just store it in the HTTPSession.